# Homework Help - Create a function to allocate a struct and fill in the fields

Tags: c, struct

I'm having trouble writing a function that creates a struct and fills in the fields with data passed in as parameters. I'm very new to C, so this is very challenging for me.

I created a struct called 'Employee' which has fields for name, birth year, and start year.

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int birthyear;
    int startyear;
}   Employee;
```

For the function I created, I keep getting errors about dereferncing pointers to incomplete types. Also, I get an error for invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type struct Employee.

```
Employee* make_employee(char *name, int birthyear, int startyear) {
    struct Employee* newemployee = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    newemployee->name = name;
    newemployee->birthyear = birthyear;
    newemployee->startyear = startyear;
    return newemployee;
}
```

I'm sure I'm just making very simple mistakes, but help and explanation would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.

Answer (score 2):

Your only problem is this line:

```
struct Employee* newemployee = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

The `struct` keywords are wrong in your case. Because of the way you defined and `typedef`ed your structure, there is no such type `struct Employee` - only the simple typedef `Employee` is valid.  Just delete all three `struct` there and you should be fine:

```
Employee *newemployee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
```

I deleted the unnecessary cast for clarity.

Alternatively, you could change your structure definition to include a structure name, rather than just making an anonymous structure and `typdef`ing it:

```
typedef struct Employee {
    char *name;
    int birthyear;
    int startyearl
} Employee;
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much. Now I have to make a function that prints the struct after being created, but that shouldn't be too bad. Thanks a ton!